# How to create the following layout using CSS-grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

this is actually my first post.

I would like to achieve the following result using CSS-grid and I'm not really sure how.

I'm hoping you guys could help me as I'm quite new to CSS-grid.

CSS-GRID layout I wish to achieve:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take some minute to read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post what you have tried/researched so far. I believe you might want to look into the [bootstrap framework](https://getbootstrap.com) to get a general idea of how a grid layout works.

Comment: hello, you could start digging how grid works and then try it ourself  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ https://gridbyexample.com/  From there you might get help where you fail or misunderstand ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use boostrap framework. You can easily divide your website with it.
This is how to implement it: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp
This is how to divide website: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Now the source code but remember this is not what is stackoverflow for, you should do some research any try something before you ask here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Popper JS -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            div {border:2px solid black} 
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div>Item</div>
                <div>Item</div>
                <div>Item</div>
                <div>Item</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                Item
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">Item</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">Item</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                Item
            </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions might be a little off, but you can adjust them to your liking. Make sure you use Firefox when using grids because it has the best editor for it to display the grids and grid numbers.

https://codepen.io/coltcarnevale/pen/zypOVB

```
   <div class="container">
  <div class="item item__1">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item item__2">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item item__3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item item__4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item item__5">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item item__6">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item item__7">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item item__8">Item 8</div>
</div>
```

CSS FILE

```
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 30px;

  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 150px repeat(2, 130px) 200px;

  grid-gap: 30px;
}

.item {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;

  &__2 {
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }

  &__3 {
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
  }

  &__4 {
    grid-row: 1 / 4;
    grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  }

  &__5 {
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
  }

  &__6 {
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
  }

  &__7 {
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
  }

  &__8 {
    grid-column: 4 / 5;
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be of your help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 80px 160px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}



.item3 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 6;
    grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
    grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.item6,.item7,.item8 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 6;

}





</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">item</div>
  <div class="item2">item</div>
  <div class="item3">item</div>
  <div class="item4">item</div>
  <div class="item5">item</div>  
  <div class="item6">item</div>
  <div class="item7">item</div>  
  <div class="item8">item</div>  




</div>


</body>
</html>
```